# "My mule don't like people laughing", Why is "don't" used instead of "doesn't"?

Tags: word-choice, singular-subject-and-verb

This is a quote from Clint Eastwood's character Joe, in the movie *A Fistful of Dollars*:

> You see, my mule don't like people laughing. He gets the crazy idea you're laughin' at him. Now if you apologize, like I know you're going to, I might convince him that you really didn't mean it.

[Link to the movie clip](https://youtu.be/mkr0bwV5YWE?t=53s)

Why does he use the word "don't" instead of "doesn't"?

Comment: It's a representation of informal, possibly 'uneducated' speech - as is the dropping of the final 'g' in 'laughing'.

Comment: It’s tough-guy talk, an indirect threat, which is carried out in the movie.

Comment: It's a form of English which is nowhere standard, but common in many parts of the English speaking world.

Comment: It's because my mule don't speak good English like me.

Answer (score -1):

I actually have a few theories my first theory is back in that timeframe men or boys didn’t go to school as long as girls did so maybe his grammar isn’t as good also my second theory is that back then people did talk a little differently than we do now in my third and final theory is they told him to say it like that that’s what they told Clint to say

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please  use proper punctuation on this site. Thanks.